# Multi filter search on a relational DB data(Mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, filter

I have scenario where i have 9-10 columns in my DB schema (col1......col10).I am aware of covering indexes and as well as how mysql can use only one index for a given search query.
When the filters were limited , i was able to optimize my query patterns to maintain order to use indexing properly.
But now i have a requirement of dynamic filters, e.g i can get any of the below filters in the request.

```
col1 > x and col2<y.
Col8 > z
Col4> a anc col9 <b.
col 6 <m
etc.
```

So we can see either i create separate indexes on all columns(this is unfeasible) or use covering indexes but i cant do that since i am not sure which filtering column will be skipped when request comes.
Any efficient way to handle this or i switch to some other DB option(open for this)

regards
Ankit

Comment: Just create indexes on most frequently filtered columns. Query optimizer will use them whenever possible, regardless of how your query condition looks (if there is indexed column somewhere in the query condition, the index will be used).

Comment: sorry but this is not what i was looking for.I already mentioned in my initial question that filter can have any number of columns(even 1 every time), it is incredibly poor to create index on all 10 columns.

Comment: I think it is not poor to have many indexes if you use them often. The only drawbacks are the data space on disk which index needs and the fact that after data modification index needs to be updated, which takes some time. But if you query a lot and write less often, it is not a problem.